# set style conditionally with if value of variable matches specific string in array

Tags: d3.js, coffeescript

```
console.log(d3.selectAll(".bubble-label-name").filter((d) -> textValue(d) == wor).style("background-color", "red"))
```

Here I am able to set the background-color based on the fiter that requires that (d) -> textValue(d) matches wor - which is a variable containing a string.

I would like to use variable wor being an array, so that the filter is true when (d) -> textValue(d) matches a string in array wor.

Comment: Is `textValue` a function?  Wouldn't it just be `(d) -> textValue(d) in wor`?  Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/i220NtvJA6ZK7jRjiqlO?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, thank you - that works. Thank you very much.I want to match the content from localStorage against (d) -> textValue(d). It is a vocabulary learning application. The user can 'mark' difficult words - setting them to localStorage. When the wordlist is rendered the next time, I would like the 'marked' words to appear in red. I think yous solution will do that. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct code for the filter as Mark pointed out.

```
wor = something # an array

console.log(d3.selectAll(".bubble-label-name").filter((d) -> textValue(d) in wor).style("background-color", "red"))
```